# Writing JOIN queries in PostgreSQL with multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got 3 tables that look vaguely like this:

```
Users
----------
UserID
Name
Phone

User Groups
-----------
GroupID
GroupActivity

Group Membership
---------------
UserID
GroupID
```

I am trying to print the user name and phone number for all the groups with members undertaking a certain activity. For example, group 1 activity = knitting, group 2 activity = sewing and group 3 activity = knitting. I want to select all the members that are knitting but I am unsure how to join the three tables in one query. This is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT                                                                   
users.name, users.phone, groups.activity  
FROM users
INNER JOIN group_membership ON group_membership.userID = users.userID 
WHERE groups.activity = 'Knitting';
```

This ends up throwing the following error:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "groups"

To fix this I tried adding `teams` to the `FROM` clause like so:

```
FROM users,groups
```

However, this in turn gives me this error:

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "members"

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT                                                                   
users.name, users.phone, user_groups.activity  
FROM users 
INNER JOIN group_membership ON group_membership.userID = users.userID 
inner join user_groups on user_groups.groupid = group_membership.groupid
WHERE user_groups.activity = 'Knitting';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have that shorter with table aliases and the `USING` clause:

```
SELECT ug.groupid, u.name, u.phone
FROM   user_groups ug
JOIN   group_membership USING (groupid)
JOIN   users u          USING (userid)
WHERE  ug.activity = 'knitting';
```

[Details in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html)